# Do you use ReSharper full time, or only enable it when needed?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Based on a [multitude of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=disable+resharper) related to temporarily disabling ReSharper, and also on certain research data, I can see that a considerable share of ReSharper users have it disabled most of the time. They tend to enable it for a limited period of time (say, several hours), do whatever they need to do using its functionality, and disable it back until the next time they feel they need to use it.

If you're using ReSharper (or other similar VS extensions, to that matter) in such occasional manner, can you clarify why you're doing this?

Is your behavior based on performance, or other considerations?

What kinds of tasks do you enable ReSharper for in this scenario?

Comment: I am forced to use it at my new job, and cannot bloody stand it. I've turned off basically every feature, visual studio gets in your way enough as it is without this pile typing all kinds of extra characters for me. I think if you're a fast typist and know where the syntax goes, you really don't need something like this putting it there for you.

Comment: I had to uninstall it due to performance issues and because it would crash VS2010 pretty frequently. There's a split in the developers I work with who are like me and have experienced nothing but trouble with R# and those who can't code without it.

Comment: Well in addition to being a fast typer, you should be a memory giant: http://web.archive.org/web/20100503013518/http://blog.briandicroce.com/2008/05/12/the-case-for-resharper-in-the-enterprise/ Many hated the tool initially only to find themselves dependent (in a good way) in a little while. Anyway, you can turn off code completion both in R# and VS, and this will do the trick. Give it a try and explore it: R# is so much more than a completion tool: http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/why-resharper-is-awesome (shameless plug over)

Comment: @birryree Is there a correlation between poor hardware and poor R# experience on your team, or does R# bring all sorts of trouble irrelevant of hardware specs? Crashes per se are usually caused by insufficient memory (R# is a complex tool and it does need its fair share of memory) but other reasons are possible, too.

Comment: @gorohoroh - Every single machine we use has the same hardware - quad core 3.2 Ghz CPUs (AMD Phenom X2s), and 16 GB RAM (though VS itself is a 32-bit application so it will not use anywhere near that amount). We all have either WD Raptors or SSD drives, and the developer with an SSD also uninstalled R# because it lags his VS instance. I couldn't code with R# installed for more than 10 minutes before VS2010 crashed. Of course, other people had it running fine. I think the major difference might be that those of us with R# problems work on significantly larger code bases than others.

Comment: @birryree Thanks! That's very solid specs. If you happen to use R# again and continue to face the issues, I'd appreciate if you go to ReSharper > Help > Profile Visual Studio to make a quick performance snapshot and send it to us at JB for investigation.

Answer (score 4):

Looking through those links they are seem mainly to be about disabling certain features of Resharper rather than the product itself. Some of the formatting ones can be a pain if you don't know how to configure them (I don't really and just email their support).

You can disable the whole thing simply enough if you want though, it uses a lot of memory which is understandable but potentially problematic.

I refactor a lot, constantly, so it makes no sense to not have it switched on for me. That plus all the editor helpers.

I can't* code without it being installed, a core dozen or so features are wired into my muscle memory, things like Ctrl+T and Shift+Alt+L.

For VS 2010 I'd also recommend VS productivity tools. It has three or four things I love, but I'll just mention the fact it uses your editor scroll bar as a place to put extra information, like the location of search results in the file, breakpoints, that sort of thing.

*Ok, look I can code in notepad if I have to, but given the choice, I would never use Visual Studio again without Resharper.

Comment: My initial guess was that performance/memory usage was the major factor in this kind of occasional usage but I wonder if there are patterns that are rather based on development practices. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

> Is your behavior based on performance, or other considerations?

**Performance of daily used tools** is important and needs special attention in my view.

I have experienced issues while having Resharper installed on my development machine with VS2010. The main reason was in lack of memory(i had just 4GB). My VS solution has 48 projects including test projects as well. I saw usage of almost 2-3GB memory while debugging. As well as, unresponsiveness of VS2010. The usage of memory by ReSharper was around 300-700MB.

Solution to this issues was simple. Upgrade your hardware for productivity. After upgrading desktop memory to 8GB and installing SSD i am rarely face with such situation.
However, i also do believe you may disable ReSharper by using the configuration.

Overall, i think `Resharper is very useful tool and provides a big productivity boost` during the enterprise software development.

Comment: Thanks! I concur: upgrading hardware is fast, easy and very efficient, yet many companies are reluctant to doing it.